# Android - прозрачный цвет текста

Tags: xml, android

Доброго времени суток. Заметил одну странную вещь: в PSD макете нарисованной активности цвет текста с прозрачностью 60% более яркий, насыщенный. Если в приложении для TextView выставить цвет текста #99FFFFF - аналогичный тому, что использован в макете, то тут цвет какой-то более тусклый и темный. Из-за чего такая разница и как с этим бороться?

Comment: тем, что фотошоп установлен на компе, а смотрите не телефоне. Возможно, нужно на телефоне подкрутить яркость. А возможно, просто такой экран.

Comment: @KoVadim, Пробовал на 2х аппаратах с разной цветопередачей, все равно не то... Так же пробовал открывать макет и на нетбуке с плохой цветопередачей (цвета более тусклые, чем на стационарнике), но все равно даже на нетбуке цвета смотрятся лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй для цвета alpha+RGB. К примеру:

```
 // alpha 0 до 255
 int alpha = 0;
 ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setTextColor(Color.argb(alpha, 255, 0, 0));
```